# How to: Access ControlTemplate-Generated Elements which do not have a name in a style

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to address ControlTemplate generated elements which do not have a name in a stlye?

The following is an excerpt from the default control template of a wpf combobox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0" MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Popup IsOpen="False" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" AllowsTransparency="True" Name="PART_Popup" Margin="1,1,1,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    </Popup>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    </ToggleButton>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now what I want to do is to change the IsHitTestVisible property of the ContentPresenter (which does not have a name in the ControlTemplate) to true, for example:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}"  >
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Is it even possible?

If not, can it be done by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `IsHitTestVisible` is set locally. So to override that, we need to set it locally (just doable in codebehind). We can also set its value by using a source of higher precendence such as Animation. Here you can define a style targeting the `ContentPresenter`. In that style define an EventTrigger for `Loaded` event and use `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` with `DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame` like this:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
             <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                  <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                     <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                  </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>      
               </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
           </EventTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

More about [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).